# Boxplot en R con frecuencias y marca de clase

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

buenas noches. Quisiera saber, como construir un boxplot sencillo (con ggplot2) teniendo como dato de ingreso las marcas de clase y las frecuencias:

[image: Distribución de frecuencias]

como pueden ver, necesito calcular un unico boxplot, teniendo en consideracion las frecuencias de cada uno de los precios.
En excel, calculados manualmente, los resultados obtenidos fueron:
Q1: 33
Q2: 42,8
Q3: 62,3
IQ: 29,3
Todos los gráficos que vi, tienen de ingreso datos del muestreo, pero acá solo poseo las frecuencias por intervalo de Precio. Quisiera saber como obtener el boxplot q contenga cada uno de los Q1, Q2 y Q3 obtenidos.

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Si sólo tienes como datos las marcas de clase y las frecuencias no es posible que Q1 sea 33, ya que el valor mínimo sería 35.

Teniendo esto en cuenta, creo que lo más sencillo para lo que buscas es construír un vector (hay que construírlo como dataframe) con las marcas de clase repetidas según la frecuencia y utilizar la función `geom_boxplot` de `ggplot2`:

```
datos <- data.frame("x"=c(rep(35,7),rep(45,5),rep(55,2),rep(65,3),rep(75,3)))
ggplot(datos, aes(y=datos)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Como te digo, los valores que salen son distintos (Q1=35, Q2=45, Q3=65), así que no sé si esto te ayuda a resolver tu duda.

Comment: Julio, agradezco tu respuesta. De todas formas, este método no me funcionó, me genera un error por el hecho de tratarse de una lista y no puedo resolverlo.
Saludos,

Comment: Vaya! Culpa mía, copié y pegué una versión errónea. Si cambias la segunda línea por ```ggplot(datos, aes(y=x)) + geom_boxplot()``` debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Con esta totalización, has perdido la información de las frecuencias de precios real, ahora tienes una muestra agrupada que se reduce a 5 precios específicos, claramente los quantiles serán distintos a la muestra inicial. De todas formas, puedes generar un `boxplot` "expandiendo" cada precio por la cantidad dada en `fa`. Si estás usando `tidyverse/tidyr` puedes hacer:

```
library(tidyverse)

datos <- data.frame(`Marca de clase` = c(35, 45, 55, 65, 75),
                    `fa` = c(7, 5, 2, 3, 3),
                    check.names = FALSE)

datos %>% 
  uncount(fa) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=`Marca de clase`, x="precio")) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun=quantile,
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=.42), size=3.5)
```

En este caso la "magia" la hace `uncount(fa)` que expande cada observación por el valor de `fa`, de esta forma los datos quedan de la forma natural en que los trabaja `geom_boxplot()`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, dado que tienes los quantiles y estan claros los precios máximos y mínimos, podrías generar una muestra "sintética" que respete aproximadamente la distribución original:

```
set.seed(2022)

n <- 1e6
quantiles <- c(30, 33, 42.8, 62.3, 79)
muestra <- data.frame(Precio = c(
  runif(n/4,quantiles[1],quantiles[2]),
  runif(n/4,quantiles[2],quantiles[3]),
  runif(n/4,quantiles[3],quantiles[4]),
  runif(n/4,quantiles[4],quantiles[5])
))

muestra %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y=Precio, x="precio")) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(geom="text", fun=quantile,
               aes(label=sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..)),
               position=position_nudge(x=.42), size=3.5)
```

El tamaño de la muestra debe ser mayor a la orginal con 20 casos para aproximarnos a los quantiles originales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, Patricio! Que función cumpliría el "n <- 1e6" en este caso?
Recién me estoy iniciando en R y hay cosas que nunca las vi, así como el %>%.
Saludos,

Comment: ` 1e6 = 1000000`, es el valor de la cantidad de muestras que quieres, en este caso un millón. El `%>%`  o pipe es un operador del paquete `magitr` pero que se incorpora por defecto en muchos otros y permite anidar funciones para escribirlas de forma más clara, básicamente cuando tienes algo así: `f3(f2(f1(datos)))` puedes escribirlo como `datos %>% f1() %>% f2() %>% f3()`